# Find the relative extrema of $3x^4−36x^3+140x+200$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the relative extrema of the function:

$$3x^4−36x^3+140x+200$$

So I found the 1st derivative:

$$12x^3-108x^2+140$$

Then I got lost from here because I don't think it can be factorized, I'm trying to get the critical points then find the critical values. I'm sorry if my equations are not too good, I still don't know the most suitable equation editors for this site

Comment: Are you sure it's $140^{x}$?

Comment: In either case, according to WolframAlpha, the relative extrema are not very 'nice'.

Comment: That's where the confusion came from but it's what my maths lecturer gave us as assignment

Comment: The derivative of $140^x$ is not $140$ but rather $\ln(140)\,140^x$.

Comment: **Meta-cheating**, instructors don't normally inflict such difficult problems, when the obvious point of such an expression is for you to realize the significance of the first and second derivatives.  The place for you to start is to **re-read and respond to** the comment of Joshua Wang.

Comment: @user2661923 I posted it exactly how my lecturer put it

Comment: "I posted it exactly how my lecturer put it".  Taking your statement at face-value, one is left with two **meta-cheating** anomalies: [1] In order to attack the problem, you have to calculate the 1st and 2nd derivatives, but by your own reaction to Joe's answer, you (apparently) were never taught how to differentiate $(140^x)$. ...see next comment

Comment: [2] As stated, the problem is ugly.  short of estimating $\log(140) \approx 4.94$ and examining $f'(x), f''(x)$ for such values as $\{\pm 5.5, \pm 5, \pm 4.5, \cdots, 0\}$ and then trying to find an **interval** such that the interval must contain a critical point, I don't see how else to attack the problem, without the aid of computer software.  In my opinion, using computer software makes the whole problem pointless.

Comment: I'm sorry y'all, I meant 140x not 140^x. We all make mistakes at one point, no one is perfect, so I don't deserve all these toxic comments

Comment: [1] You didn't proofread your query either while posting, or afterwards.  [2] You didn't immediately react to Joshua Wang's comment and show initiative on checking for a mistake.  [3] When I referred you to Joshua Wang's comment, you still insisted that your query was correctly given. [4] You have complained about *toxic* comments.  What *toxic* comments? From what I can see, each reaction to your query was entirely mathematical in nature.

Comment: @user2661923 it's either your interested in helping me out or not. With that being said, I won't react again.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $140^x$ is not $140$. Keep in mind that there are four distinct formulae for evaluating the derivative of a number raised to another number:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}(a^b) &= 0 \\
\frac{d}{dx}(x^a) &= ax^{a-1} \\
\frac{d}{dx}(a^x) &= a^x \log a \\
\frac{d}{dx}(x^x) &= x^x \left(\log x + 1\right)
\end{align}
The first two formulae should be familiar to you: the derivative of a constant is zero, and the derivative of $x^a$, where $a$ is a constant, simply involves the application of the power rule. The last two might not be so familiar. But it is the third, not the second formula that applies here:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(140^x) = 140^x \log(140) \, .
$$
If you use this formula, then should be able to find the extrema of the function is question by setting the first derivative equal to $0$.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know the derivative will not be 140, thanks for this. Though I'm still unable to find the extrema of the function because I'm not aligned to the 140x log(140)  function

Comment: @Chinez I think you should speak to your teacher about this. As people have already noted in the comments, this problem is unlikely to have a 'nice' solution. You have an $x$ as the base of an exponential function on one term and as the power of an exponential function in another. This means that the answer cannot be solved using 'elementary methods', and has to be approximated using numerical methods.

Comment: Well I made a mistake, it's 140x, not 140^x sorry

Comment: @Chinez In that case, how are you finding this problem? Have you got the solution now?

Comment: I think so but I'm still not quite sure, my friend in my department told me to find the 2nd derivative then substitute the critical values inside the original function in order to get the final answer, but I would still like you to help if you know the solution

Comment: @Chinez Yes, the second derivative is important. But what you have worked out so far: have you found the critical points by setting $f'(x)$ equal to zero and solving the resulting equation? Only then does the second derivative become important.

Comment: I've only found the 1st derivative which was the equation above. Then I got stuck because 12x^3−108x^2+140 cannot be factorized(140) is the odd one. Have no idea what to do from there

Comment: @Chinez I looked up the solution to that question and it doesn't seem to have a 'nice' form. Perhaps you should clarify with your teacher.

Comment: I teamed with my mates, we've solved and submitted the assignment. But thanks though

Comment: @Chinez: Good news! And good luck with your studies. For me, calculus is the most beautiful area of mathematics.